# C/C++: Easily unzip to memory

Tags: c++, c, zip, unzip

I need to find a library that allows me to *easily* get a directory listing of all the files inside a ZIP archive and allows me to extract any given file inside the archive to memory (a buffer). Preferably, it should be a high-level library since my requirements aren't very complex (what I mentioned above is pretty much all I need).

Previously I tried PhysFS which has the behavior I need (easily access files inside an archive), but it's unsuitable because of other reasons (there are many archives and PhysFS would require me to mount all of them individually, which is not an option). Another library that kinda has the functionality I need is [Chilkat](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/vcZipIterate.asp), but it's shareware so I can't use it either.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: C or C++ are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm comfortable with both. If you insist, I'd pick C++. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While .zip uses zlib http://zlib.net compression, it alone is not sufficient to get a directory listing from a .zip file.

You also need code that can read the .zip dictionary format.  Check out Minizip http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html.  It provides a code and simple zip/unzip command line executables.

*edit 2* The code is entirely C (so is Zlib) -- the page has links to two c++ wrapper libs that both seem to be dead links.

Comment: I'm seconding minizip --- it's great. The API is a bit peculiar and there are some minor bugs when writing zipfiles, particularly when you want to do odd stuff like writing files with different compression settings, but it's faster, smaller and easier to use than libzip and much easier to understand.

Comment: Minizip seems to be good. I also found this very simple wrapper of Minizip that helped me understand how it should be used: [http://code.google.com/p/microzip/...1d80da08c](http://code.google.com/p/microzip/source/browse/src/microzip/Unzipper.cpp?r=c18cac3b6126cfd1a08b3e4543801b21d80da08c)

Answer (score 2):

How about zlib?  http://zlib.net/  "A Massively Spiffy Yet Delicately Unobtrusive Compression Library (Also Free, Not to Mention Unencumbered by Patents)"

Comment: zlib doesn't support .zip. It contains minizip, that is used to zip/unzip, but one has to write a Unix wrapper by himself.